# Fail to use switch statement based on typeof object

Tags: angularjs, html, typescript, angular

in my html im using a function to call `getObjInfo(oBJ)` And im passing it the object. now I have switch statement in my `getObjInfo` func to return something base on the type of the obj that got passed by the html, it looks like this (Cars , People , Animals are interfaces):

```
public getObjInfo(elem: Cars | People | Animals) {
    switch (typeof(elem)) {
      case 'Cars':
        return elem.color;
      case 'People':
        return elem.age;
      case 'Animals':
        return elem.name;
    }
  }
```

this is the html that passes it:

```
  <div class="list-bg" *ngFor="#obj of listToDisplay">
    {{getObjInfo(obj)}}
  </div>
```

i dont get any errors, its just dosent work...what am i doing wrong..?

Comment: What are these `Cars`, `People` and `Animals`? Interfaces, classes?

Comment: In TypeScript interfaces only exist statically but are not retained when built to JS. If `Cars`, `People`, `Animals` are actually interfaces it is expected to not work.

Comment: @NitzanTomer they are interfaces, sorry for didnt say

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer they are interfaces, so how do I make it work?

Comment: Change them to classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `Cars`, `People` and `Animals` are interfaces then you cannot do it with `typeof` as these interfaces only exist at compilation time and are absent in runtime.

You can have a function that checks the properties of the `elem` and returns the type:

```
function getElementType(elem: Cars | People | Animals) {
    if (elem.carProperty1 && elem.carProperty2) {
        return "Cars";
    }

    if (elem.peopleProperty1 && elem.peopleProperty2) {
        return "People";
    }

    if (elem.animalsProperty1 && elem.animalsProperty2) {
        return "Animals";
    }

    return "unknown"
}
```

And then:

```
public getObjInfo(elem: Cars | People | Animals) {
    switch (getElementType(elem)) {
        case 'Cars':
            return elem.color;
        case 'People':
            return elem.age;
        case 'Animals':
            return elem.name;
    }
}
```

However, if you turn those interfaces into classes you'll be able to do that using `instanceof`.